# Запятая перед «и»

Tags: пунктуация

В таком предложении: «Им принесли чай и сказали, чтобы он вернулся домой» нужна запятая, перед «и»? Склоняюсь, что не нужна, однородные сказуемые....

Comment: Запятая не нужна, а "детскую" стилистику нужно как-то исправить.

Comment: Это для примера....